# A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?'

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?'.

Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?'.I want to take the point from firebase database into x-point to make line graph.

```
void fetchDataFromFirebase() {
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .ref('1TJ5Srs0JsEvXaiehwPgCkJ8Ywqsoj5ERRCVcCFhGoDA/swh');

  databaseReference.once().then((DatabaseEvent databaseEvent) {
    if (databaseEvent.snapshot.value != null) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic>? values = databaseEvent.snapshot.value;
      List<DataPoint> newDataPoints = [];

      values.forEach((key, value) {
        if (value['Num'] != null && value['Swh'] != null) {
          int? num = value['Num'] as int?;
          double? swh = value['Swh'] as double?;

          if (num != null && swh != null && num >= 1 && num <= 10) {
            newDataPoints.add(DataPoint(num.toDouble(), swh));
          }
        }
      });

      setState(() {
        dataPoints.clear();
        dataPoints.addAll(newDataPoints);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

so how to make it possible? before this I to do like this but still got error for 'foreach'

```
void fetchDataFromFirebase() {
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .ref('1TJ5Srs0JsEvXaiehwPgCkJ8Ywqsoj5ERRCVcCFhGoDA/swh');

  databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
      List<DataPoint> newDataPoints = [];

      dataSnapshot.value!.forEach((key, value) {
        if (value['Num'] != null && value['Swh'] != null) {
          int? num = value['Num'] as int?;
          double? swh = value['Swh'] as double?;

          if (num != null && swh != null && num >= 1 && num <= 10) {
            newDataPoints.add(DataPoint(num.toDouble(), swh));
          }
        }
      });

      setState(() {
        dataPoints.clear();
        dataPoints.addAll(newDataPoints);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried what it actually suggested? "casting the right-hand type to 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?", which would be writing `Map<dynamic, dynamic>? values = databaseEvent.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>?;`

Comment: already did it but still got error:

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?' in type cast)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this issue by casting `Map<dynamic, dynamic>? values = databaseEvent.snapshot.value;` as `Map<dynamic,dynamic>?`

```
void fetchDataFromFirebase() {
      final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .ref('1TJ5Srs0JsEvXaiehwPgCkJ8Ywqsoj5ERRCVcCFhGoDA/swh');
    
      databaseReference.once().then((DatabaseEvent databaseEvent) {
        if (databaseEvent.snapshot.value != null) {
          Map<String, dynamic> map = snap.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>
 // Explicit cast
    
          if (values != null) { // you shpuld check is it null or not null
            List<DataPoint> newDataPoints = [];
    
            values.forEach((key, value) {
              if (value['Num'] != null && value['Swh'] != null) {
                int? num = value['Num'] as int?;
                double? swh = value['Swh'] as double?;
    
                if (num != null && swh != null && num >= 1 && num <= 10) {
                  newDataPoints.add(DataPoint(num.toDouble(), swh));
                }
              }
            });
    
            setState(() {
              dataPoints.clear();
              dataPoints.addAll(newDataPoints);
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: still got the error:
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?' in type cast)

Comment: do you have any suggestion or another way I can follow the new coding for graph that I can change the coordinate from firebase or google sheet